# calling upon an array value by another array's value

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

ok this is hard for me to describe which is probably why I am having a hard time figuring out the code.

So I have an array:

`$new_url_array[]`

and it has some values, imagine it looks like this:

```
1 -> urla
2 -> urlb
3 -> urlc
4 -> urld
```

AND THEN I HAVE an array called `$gotfrompost[]`  it looks like this:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 1
3 -> 4
4 -> 2
```

So what I need to be able to do is ask for the value of `$new_url_array[]` BASED ON the VALUE of `$gotfrompost[]` so that if I input $a (as $a = 1)

I want it to first confer with got from post, see that `$gotfrompost[1] = 3` THEN go get `$new_url_array[3]` which outputs to `URLC`

do you see what I mean?

I want this all becuase I am trying to put some data in a sql db like so and this is the best code that I can think of but it doesn't work. Also there is a loop going on, where `$a` is simply incremented until it hits the total number of values. (`$ln' is just an id row that counts up as well)

```
$dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist12 (url, listnum) values ('$new_url_array[$gotfrompost[$a]]','$ln')");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What result to you get when you echo `$new_url_array[$gotfrompost[$a]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly braces and try

```
$dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist12 (url, listnum) values ('".{$new_url_array[$gotfrompost[$a]]}."','$ln')");
```

Comment: that by itself didn't work but it gave me the idea that lead to it getting fixed! thanks so much

Comment: @WillDelphia, will you tell what did work so that this question is useful to others?

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the value `$new_url_array[$gotfrompost[$a]]`. You should also change your variable names to be more consistent.